# Insert CURRENT_TIME minus 1 hour?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with a timestamp column named "lastfed".

Does someone know how I can update that column with current time minus for example 1 hour?

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE test SET fullness = $newFullness, lastfed = CURRENT_TIME WHERE id = ?");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [date_sub()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```sql
UPDATE test 
SET fullness = $newFullness, 
    lastfed = date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
WHERE id = ?
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26080)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you that works! I´ll mark your answer as solved when the time allows!

Comment: Just a quick question, if I need it to be for example 30 minutes then how do I write that? 30 MINUTES doesn´t work...

Comment: Use MINUTE without the s at the end. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) for the available expressions. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26082) for an example.

Comment: @geek, just change the query like `date_sub(now(),interval 30 minute)`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test 
SET fullness = $newFullness, lastfed = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Using curdate in this situation is not correct. Curdate returns the date part of a timestamp. Setting a timestamp column to curdate - 30 minutes will end up at 23:30 of yesterday. [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26083) for an example.